# Rename directory based on date of file in directory

Tags: osx, directory, rename

I am looking for a smart way to bulk rename directories in my photo library based on the date the pictures were taken.

My specific use case: Export the image library from iPhoto or Aperture on OS X to a more permanent and OS-independent file and folder structure.

The input list of directories would look like this:

```
1.2.2012
input_directory_name
```

The renamed output should look like this:

```
2012-02-01 - 2012-02-22
2012-03-14 - 2012-03-14 input_directory_name
```

The dates should be picked either from the creation dates of the pictures in the directory (oldest / newest date) or alternatively from the metadata of the files (JPEG, TIFF, RAW...).

If the input_directory_name is looking like a date "1.2.2012" then it should be skipped.

If the input_directory_name contains text the text should be added to the new directory name. Reason: Unnamed events in iPhoto / Aperture are autmatically tagged with a date which unfortunately has the badly sortable order of DD.MM.YYYY

I googled a bit but couldn't easily find a clever way - possibly someone else has encountered this issue before?

Comment: IIRC, the exitool manage page has examples for that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: if you are going to be trying solutions use a full copy or a copy of a subset of the pictures to avoid disaster.

You could try something along the lines of:

```
for folder in $(ls -l | awk '{print $9}'); 
    do <magic here>;
done
```

The magic could be something like using the `identify` command if this is available to you. 
From what I read it can read exif data from pictures. Based on this you could perhaps create a folder or move the directory etc etc.